# Utilizing Flicker public feed with JSONP gets and error

Tags: angular, typescript, jsonp

Im struggling with flicker api. Public feed to be exact.

My code looks like this

```
public getFeed(): void {
    const apiURL = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=space&tagmode=all&format=json';
    this.http.jsonp(apiURL, 'callback')
      .pipe(tap(data => data)).subscribe(this.log);
  }

  public log(json) {
    console.log(json);
  }
```

when I run the getFeed method form component it throws the errors in console:

```
ReferenceError: jsonFlickrFeed is not defined
photos_public.gne:1:1
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "JSONP Error", url: "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=space&tagmode=all&format=json&callback=ng_jsonp_callback_0", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=space&tagmode=all&format=json&callback=ng_jsonp_callback_0: 0 JSONP Error", error: Error }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why it says jsonFlickerFeed is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL appears OK in that if put into a browser it returns a function call with data as you would expect with JSONP.

It appears to need a callback function called 'jsonFlickrFeed' which it can call.

Perhaps you should write a short function to display some data.